# Discrete group action and openness of stabilizer

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups, galois-representations

Let $G$ be a topological group that acts (topologically) on a topological space $V=\mathbb Q_p^n$. Moreover, let us assume that this action is linear, in other words, the action gives a linear representation $\rho: G \to GL(V)$.

I wonder whether the openness of stabilizers $G_x$ for all $x \in X$ implies that $\rho(G)$ is discrete in $GL(V)$, and vice versa. I tried to prove but still, I am not sure that this is true.

The motivation for this question comes from $p$-adic Galois representations. For $p$-adic field $K$, it is known that the $\overline K$-admissibility of a $p$-adic representation $V$ of $G_K$ (the absolute Galois group of $K$) is equivalent to the discreteness of an action $G_K$ on $V$. And it is stated that this is implied once if one proves that $G_{K,x}$ is open for arbitrary $x \in V$.

Comment: What do you mean $\rho(G)$ being discrete in $GL(V)$? Because $\rho(G) : V \rightarrow V$ is a linear map. What is a discrete linear map?

Comment: user57 // Since $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q_p^n$ in my motivational example, $GL(V)$ has the natural topology for which $GL(V)$ is Hausdorff and locally compact. $\rho(G)$ being discrete in $GL(V)$ means this subset has the discrete topology under the inherited topology. I forgot to give the conditions about $V$, but you may just think that $V=\mathbb Q_p^n$, or $\mathbb Q^n$ if you are not familiar with $\mathbb Q_p$.

Comment: @user57 $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ is a homomorphism, so $\rho(G)$ is the image of this homomorphism (so is a subgroup), and in particular is a subset of the topological space $GL(V)$, so it does make sense to ask about discreteness. You’re thinking of an individual $\rho(g)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute Galois group is compact, so we will assume $G$ is compact in what follows.

Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in V$ be a basis; this induces an homeomorphism $\Psi$ from $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ to the space of frames $\mathrm{F}(V)$ given by
$$T \overset{\Psi}\longmapsto (Tv_1, \ldots Tv_n).$$

Let $\operatorname{orb}_G(v)$ and $\operatorname{stab}_G(v)$ denote the orbit and stabilizer of a vector $v$, respectively.  It suffices to prove that the orbit of each basis vector is discrete since
$$
\rho(G) \overset{\Psi}\hookrightarrow  \prod_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{orb}_G(v_i).
$$
Consider the map $\rho_i \colon G \to V$ given by $\rho_i(g) = gv_i$. Let $u \in \rho_i(G)$, meaning that $u = gv_i$ for some $g \in G$. Then the fiber over $u$ is given by
$$\rho_i^{-1}(\{u\}) = g\operatorname{stab}_G(v_i).$$

Since the fibers of $\rho_i$ are precisely the cosets of the stabilizer, the universal property of the quotient yields a continuous bijection $\widetilde{\rho}_i \, \colon G / \operatorname{stab}_G(v_i) \to \operatorname{orb}_G(v_i)$, which is actually a homeomorphism, since $G$ is compact and $V$ is Hausdorff.

To wrap up, note that the quotient $G / \operatorname{stab}_G(v_i)$ is discrete, since $\operatorname{stab}_G(v_i)$ is open.

Comment: Clever and clear answer. The idea of the proof seems common so that one can easily apply the same idea to deal with the same or similar object. Thank you so much.